# Can we dynamically show the record type on the Child object based on a checkbox field on Parent object with configuration only?

Tags: javascript, configuration

**Scenario :** I have two objects **Parent(Budget Header)** and **Child(Budget Child)**. There is a Checkbox field on Parent object **'Show Extended Budget'** . There are 2 record types on Child object **'Normal Budget'** and **'Extended Budget'**.

**Requirement :** If the `Show Extended Budget = FALSE` then while creating Child record both the record types should show. And if `Show Extended Budget = TRUE` then only the **'Extended Budget'** record type should show while creating the child records. Is it possible without creating a V.F Page ?

**Solution Tried :** I had created a formula field on Child object same as **'Show Extended Budget'** on Parent object so that value from Parent is reflected to Child. Then I had created a workflow rule to change the record type of the Child record when the **'Show Extended Budget'** became **TRUE** on Child. But this is not working since it is a formula field and is not triggering workflow rule.

**Javascript code**

```
var returnUrl = ''; 
if({!Master_Object__c.Checkbox_Field__c} == '1') 
{ 
returnUrl = "/<First 3 character of Child object Id>/e?retURL=%2F{!Master_Object__c.Id}&cancelURL=%2F{!Master_Object__c.Id}&RecordType=Child_Object_2nd_Recordtype_Id"; 
} else { 
returnUrl = "/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=<Master_Object__Id>&retURL=%2F<Master_Object__c.ID>&save_new_url=%2Fa4a%2Fe%3FCF<Id of Lookup field on Child object to parent object>%3D{!Master_Object__c.Name}%26CF<Id of Lookup field on Child object to parent object>_lkid%3D{!Master_Object__c.Id}%26retURL%3D%252F{!Master_Object__c.Id}";
} 
window.location.href = returnUrl;
```

Comment: How are you creating the child records? Is it by clicking the new button on the related list of Parent object?

Comment: Yes...as of now by clicking new button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Onclick JavaScript List type button. Hide the default New button from the related list and add this new button. The button logic should be somewhat like below. Check the checkbox value, based on that either drive the user to the RecordType selection page or set the RecordType directly.

You can't change the dropdown values, so in one case show the RecordType Selection and in other case assign the RecordType. I hope this will work for you.

```
var returnUrl = '';
if (Master.checkbox == true) {
    returnUrl = "/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=<Child Object 15 digit ID>&retURL=%2F{!Master.Id}&cancelURL=%2F{!Master.Id}";
} else {
    returnUrl = "/<First 3 Character>/e?retURL=%2F{!Master.Id}&cancelURL=%2F{!Master.Id}&RecordType=CHILD-RECORDTYPE_2";
}
window.location.href = returnUrl;
```

> Update: Inside OnClick JS you will get the check box value as 0 or 1. So in actual code the `Master.checkbox == true` should look something like  `if('{!Metadata_Campaign__c.Parent_Checkbox__c}'=='1')`.

Comment: this would be a sfdc Classic solution only, right?

Comment: @cropredy yes this is a Salesforce classic solution.

Comment: @SarojBera : I have tried your solution but I am facing one issue. If I give IF condition as (Master.checkbox == true) then I am getting the error on clicking the new button as 'true is not defined' . If i give true in quotes then it is working for the 'FALSE' condition and not working for true condition. Means it is redirecting me to the page of 2nd record type even if the checkbox is true.

Comment: Is there any way to debug and check that what is the value of checkbox which the java script is taking ?

Comment: @Ruchi Yes you can use `console.log()` to print the values in JavaScript console. Check this link for details http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp

Comment: @SarojBera: I have tried swapping the condition and the URL's. The script is always considering the 'ELSE' condition. If I place the URL of the 2nd record type in the ELSE condition then it considers only that weather checkbox is true/false. And if I put the URL to redirect to both record types in ELSE condition then script is directing to that only for both conditions.

Comment: One more issue I am facing is that this URL returnUrl = "/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=<Child Object 15 digit ID>&retURL=%2F{!Master.Id}&cancelURL=%2F{!Master.Id}";     is taking me to standard page to select the record type. But when I select 1 record type and click on continue then it does not take me to the new record page. Instead it stays on the same page.

Comment: @Ruchi What are you getting in JavaScript Console? Also if possible can you post the button JS code by editing the Question.

Comment: @SarojBera : I have posted the JS code in question. My second issue is solved. Now only the first issue is left that the code is considering only ELSE  condition. It is never going into IF condition.

Comment: @Ruchi My intention was to guide you with the flow. The actual code for `(Master.checkbox == true)` will look like `if('{!Metadata_Campaign__c.Parent_Checkbox__c}'=='1')`. Inside OnClick JS you will get the check box value as 0 or 1. Sorry for the typo. I have updated the answer also.

Comment: Yes. It was actually coz of 0/1. The issue is solved now. Thanks for all your support.

Comment: Glad that it helped!!